# I need to help fix the code C++ Win32API

Tags: c++

i'm just start to learn C++ for Win and now i at the three part of tut . so i have this code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define WIN_WIDTH 300
#define WIN_HEIGHT 200
#define class_name L"HDC"

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd , UINT Message ,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance ,HINSTANCE hPrev,PSTR cmdline ,int ishow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wndclassex ={0};
    wndclassex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclassex.cbSize = sizeof(wndclassex);
    wndclassex.lpfnWndProc;
    wndclassex.hInstance = hinstance;
    wndclassex.lpszClassName = class_name;
    wndclassex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH);
    RegisterClassEx(&wndclassex);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(class_name,L"My Second WinDow Application",
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        WIN_WIDTH,WIN_HEIGHT,NULL,NULL,hinstance,NULL);
    if(!hwnd)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    if(!hdc)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    ShowWindow(hwnd,ishow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    RECT shen;
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&shen);
    FillRect(hdc,&shen,(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

    while(1)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg,hwnd,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message==WM_QUIT)
                break;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
    UnregisterClass(class_name,hinstance);
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DefWinProc(HWND hwnd,UINT Message,WPARAM wParam ,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

    }
    return DefWinProc(hwnd,Message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

but i'm not lucky the system notice that :

```
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'device context.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in device context.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in device context.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in device context.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
The program '[15148] device context.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Please Somebody know that error just help me fix it , I'm just wanna lean window Programming . Thank you first.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger - A very useful tool in software development.

Comment: I would enable breaking on access violation in the debugger. Then see what line it stops on. You are using a null pointer. But I can not figure out in the 30 seconds I read your code..

Comment: It looks like the program exited.  You should perhaps do some tracing to find out where it is exiting.

Comment: It's not a matter of luck, only a matter of effort.

Comment: You should check the results of API calls for failure (e.g., `RegisterClassEx`). The docs for each function have specifics.

Comment: To enable breaking on access violation. Click debug then exceptions. Access Violation is in the Win32 exceptions.

Comment: You might want to change your window procedure to call `DefWindowProc` instead of being recursive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc;
```

You do realize that this does precisely nothing, and `wndclassex.lpfnWndProc` pointer remains NULL, right?

Answer (score 2):

Its just a suggestion, but consider this:

```
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc;
```

Something tells me that isn't assigning a window procedure to your registration function. (or doing anything else remotely constructive).

Try:

```
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this case is most likely the fact that you are specifying a null pointer for the window procedure here:

```
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc;
```

This is bad because you actually need a window procedure for anything to work, in the very least you have to respond to the WM_CREATE message to make sure that the window was actually created ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Then you try to redefine DefWinProc which is a function defined in one of the windows libraries that just implements the default behaviour for the messages that you don't want to process.

The first thing you need to do is find another name for the window function, I see that you defined a function prototype called WinProc, name it that instead and then change the line that I showed you earlier to

```
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
```

And it should work.